# Tailwind CSS: Text color it isn't properly set on autofill (Chrome)

Tags: html, css, laravel, tailwind-css, webkit

I have an input field on my form coded like this:

```
<input type="text" id="calle" name="direccion[calle]" required
class="w-11/12 mx-auto rounded-md border-gray-400 focus:ring-0 focus:border-green-800 h-10 pt-3 overflow-hidden my-1 text-gray-600 text-lg">
```

However, despite the text at the input is displayed with the right color in most cases, it show black when autocompleted in Chrome, like this:
[image: Before]

I've partially solved this by adding to my 'app.css' (In my Laravel app):

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
textarea:-webkit-autofill,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:hover,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:focus,
select:-webkit-autofill,
select:-webkit-autofill:hover,
select:-webkit-autofill:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #ffffff inset !important;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgb(75 85 99 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}
```

Now it shows like this when just autocompleted:
[image: After]

However, in that code, the text color is harcoded with the color value of that specific input, resulting useless when I have some other input with a different text color.
I've installed the 'autoprefixer' plugin for Tailwind, which might help.

Does anyone knows the proper way to achieve this?

Thanks a lot!

Leandro

Comment: If you actually wanted the _same_ color as the input field has specified, then you should be able to use the `currentcolor` keyword. Only you are _not_ using the exact text color of the input field there - you are applying an additional alpha-transparency, and that won't be possible using `currentcolor` with _that_ syntax.

Comment: Still trying to understand your high-level desire. Do you want the auto-complete text color to be "slightly-lighter-than-normal", regardless of what the field text color is? That was the only thing I could perceive between your two tiny screenshots.